# why background image not display?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to make simple app single page app .Actually I take background image which is placed on  it display when I used  `<ion-content class="bg"  style="position:absolute!important">` **position:absolute** but it display in small area .I need to display on whole contend .In other words in whole contend tag complete screen.
here is my code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvYdNM

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Ionic List Directive</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body >
        <ion-view>
      <ion-header-bar class=" bar bar-positive ">
      <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>    

      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="bg"  style="position:absolute!important">
          <h1 >contend</h1>
          </ion-content>
          <ion-footer-bar class=" bar bar-footer bar-positive" style="position:fixed!important">
           <h1 class="title">Fotter!</h1>
          </ion-footer-bar>
      </ion-view>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For reference, NEVER mix `!important` with inline styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tell it how big it should be.

Something like:

```
<ion-content class="bg"  style="position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 43px; bottom: 43px;">
```

should work.

Comment: thanks for answer .it works but I have one Question why you take top: 43px; bottom: 43px this .it is static value .so it create problem when we make responsive design.As I know that we should not take value in px for responsive design

Comment: `ion-header-bar` and `ion-footer-bar` have a fixed height of `43px`. If you set `top` and `bottom` to `0px` it would fit the entire screen, but be overlapped by the two bars. Screensize doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @ei you are saying footer and and header take 43 px on every screen .may i correct ?I understand 0px concept from top bottom and top .But I trying to learn if I take top 43px is it fine for all screen ?

Comment: Yes. If there aren't any breakpoints that changes the height of the bars. For your provided example it will work an every screen.

Answer (score 0):

Because your content has a bg class which doesn't cover all of your page. You set bg class's background, not the body's background. You should do this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvYpVw

```
body 
{background: url('https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/max/800/1*AJALCafqXhfLMG7iF7Ho0A.jpeg')!important;}
```

Comment: I need to add only to contend not for body.I need to add background image to contend not for body .But I need to cover whole contend width  and height

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: could you please give solution

Comment: it works but I have one Question why you take top: 43px; bottom: 43px this .it is static value .so it create problem when we make responsive design.As I know that we should not take value in px for responsive design

Comment: I tried something but it wouldn't seem to work. I didn't find a solution sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should update css rule for class bg. 
The easiest way is to just add:
          top:0;
          left:0;
          right:0;
          bottom:0;
to the bg class.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

to your `.bg` css rule